Identification of 3 pin connector for the power supply of the TI silent Model 703/707 Data Terminal
I want to restore a TI Silent 700 model 703/707 that lacks the power supply.
The power supply provides 20 VAC 35 VA with 3 pins
E1 20 VAC
E2  0 VAC
PE protected earth

The TI silent 703/707 repair manual is available online.
Now I need to find a replacement plug that matches the 3 pins of the Data Terminal.
What is the type and name of the connector?
If it is not available commercially available off-the-shelf, is there a compatible alternative available?

PS: The same question was formerly a secondary question in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/546694/

What's the pin pitch of the connector?
